# react-redux connect pattern to avoid unknown props warning with dispatch?

Tags: react-redux

`dispatch` is automatically passed as a prop when you use `connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)`. I'm not always using `dispatch` in my connected components and React 15.2 throws a warning if my connected component passes it along to its children.

Simple example:

`const Color = ({ color, ...props }) => <div {...props}>{color}</div>;`

`const CurrentColor = connect(getColorFromState)(Color);`

Now if I use the `CurrentColor` component anywhere it will throw an error because `dispatch` is passed along. Is there a pattern I can use to avoid this? The only thing I could come up with was `connect(mapStateToProps, () => ({}))(Component)` to override passing `dispatch`.

Answer (score 7):

I just solved the same issue. The `dispatch` prop is there because you are not providing `mapDispatchToProps` when you call `connect()`. You can therefore provide a dummy function to stop that prop being added:

`export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  () => ({})
)(MyPage)`

Comment: I LOVE YOU MAN,

Comment: Or even better than a function: `{}`